# Object name specification issue JMX

Tags: java, tomcat7, jmx

This is my code to read active sessions based on context

```
try{

        String serviceUrl = "service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://localhost:9001/jmxrmi";

        JMXServiceURL jmxServiceUrl = new JMXServiceURL(serviceUrl);

        JMXConnector jmxc = JMXConnectorFactory.connect(jmxServiceUrl, null);

        MBeanServerConnection conn = jmxc.getMBeanServerConnection();

        ObjectName name = new ObjectName("Catalina:type=Manager,context=/generateBill,host=localhost,port=8080");
            System.out.println("sessionCounter generateBill");
        System.out.println(conn.getAttribute(name, "sessionCounter"));

        ObjectName name2 = new ObjectName("Catalina:type=Manager,context=/generateBillService,host=localhost,port=8080");
            System.out.println("sessionCounter generateBillService");
            System.out.println(conn.getAttribute(name2, "sessionCounter"));
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

But I am getting javax.management.InstanceNotFoundException. What is the solution for this problem?

Comment: Please post the **full** error.

Comment: P.S. why is there a space in the webapp's context?

Comment: no there is no space

Comment: `context=/ testapp2` - there is in the code you posted.

Comment: I gave a dummy name. In actual condition there is no space .

Comment: Then this code is about as helpful as posting nothing, no? What does the second "C" in [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) stand for?

Comment: Sorry. Just replaced the context name as it is confidential.

Comment: Replaced the code with original

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103091/discussion-between-sreevidya-aravind-and-boris-the-spider).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ObjectName name = new ObjectName( "Catalina:type=Manager,context=/examples,host=localhost"); System.out.println(conn.getAttribute(name, "activeSessions"));

No need to specify the port.